# Error handling for node.js request

Tags: node.js

have written a node module for making http calls, but whats happening is when the call errors (due to timeout, incorrect path(done intentionally)) out a subsequent call is made ... I dont know the origin of that second request ...here is the code for the module

```
var querystring = require('querystring'),
http = require('http'),
util = require('util'),
stream = require('stream'),
Writable = stream.Writable;

exports.serviceCall = function(api, next) {
function bufferInMemory(key, options) {
    Writable.call(this, options);
    this[key] = new Buffer('');
    this._write = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        chunk = (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) ? chunk : new Buffer(chunk, encoding);
        this[key] = Buffer.concat([this[key], chunk]);
        callback();
    };
}
 util.inherits(bufferInMemory, Writable);
 api.serviceCall = function(options, callback) {
     var target = new bufferInMemory('result', {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        objectMode: true
    });
    var reqTimeout;
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.pipe(target);
        target.on('finish', function() {
            if (reqTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(reqTimeout);
                reqTimeout = null;
            }
            if (res.statusCode !== 200 && res.statusCode !== 304) {
                return callback({}, {
                    status: 'fail',
                    data: [],
                });
            } else {
                try {
                    var result;
                    result = JSON.parse(target.result.toString());
                } catch (err) {
                    result = target.result.toString();
                }
                var convertedToJson = result;
                return callback(null, {
                    status: 'success',
                    data: convertedToJson
                });
            }
        }); 
    });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
        var error = err || {};
        if (reqTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(reqTimeout);
            reqTimeout = null;
        }
        req.end();
        return callback(error, {
            status: 'fail',
            data: [],
        });
    });
    var timeoutInit = function() {
        reqTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            req.emit('error');
        }, 3000);
    };
    timeoutInit();
    /*
     *  this does not work because multiple requests can share the same socket
     */
    // req.on('socket', function(socket) {   
    //     socket.setTimeout(1000, function() {   
    //         console.log('in timeout of api service call');
    //         req.emit('error');
    //     });
    // });
    req.end();
};
next();
```

};

Am I missing something in the error handling? or it may the underlying framework (we are using actionhero.js) which makes the decision to send another call as the first one errored out ?

Comment: Does the second call only occur when the first one errors, or is it always?

Comment: it only happens in case of error... otherwise its just fine

Answer (score -1):

http will make requests asynchronously, you can not cache them as scope would be out when the error would be return from event queue..

if you want node to handle crash for uncaught exceptions then you can use process event but it is not recommended to use on production instead of use "forever" as after each uncaught exception a restart is required otherwise application can behave something different.

here is process event to handle uncaught exception..

```
 process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
   console.log(`Caught exception: ${err}`);
 });
```